# SQLite getting error that it doesn't see stored column/table despite it showing it exists

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

While working on a school project that uses SQLite, I have been having a multidute of problems with it, but after getting most of them working, the main problem I am facing right not is twofold, that as far as I know, it is not seeing all of the content that is stored in the sql, getting four main errors: "SQLiteLog: (1) table customers has no column named international in "INSERT INTO customers(salary,skills,userType,age,name,international) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", "SQLiteDataBase: Error inserting salary=123 skills=testing,coding,stuff userType=0 age=18 name=Josh international=N                                                                                                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table customers has no column named international (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO customers(salary,skills,userType,age,name,international) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", "SQLiteLog (1) no such table: security in "INSERT INTO security(username,password) VALUES (?,?)" and "SQLiteDatabase Error inserting username=Josher password=password
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: security (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO security(username,password) VALUES (?,?)". The even more confusing thing is that for some of the errors they list the very thing that the error says is missing, which I find even weirder. While there was a post about someone having a similar issue, not only is the code seem very different, but was happening while updating the database, which I haven't even attempting, and has an answer that I don't know how to apply to my current code. What exactly is causing these four error, as they seem to be connected, and have no idea what is wrong? Is there a problem with my code? Are you not allowed to have two tables at once with SQLite or something? The code below is the DBHelper,java code, and xml for the section that is having the issue.

DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "Customers.db";
    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DBNAME,null,1);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase Dat) {
        Dat.execSQL("create Table customers(name TEXT primary key, age INTEGER, skills TEXT,salary INTEGER, international TEXT,userType INTEGER)");
        Dat.execSQL("create Table security(username TEXT primary key, password TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase Dat, int i, int i1) {
        Dat.execSQL("drop Table if exists customers");
    }
    public Boolean insertData(String name, int age, String skills, int salary,String international, int userType){
        SQLiteDatabase Dat = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

        content.put("name",name);
        content.put("age",age);
        content.put("skills",skills);
        content.put("salary",salary);
        content.put("international",international);
        content.put("userType",userType);
        long result = Dat.insert("customers",null,content);
        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Boolean insertSecurity(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase Dat = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("username",username);
        content.put("password",password);
        long result = Dat.insert("security",null,content);
        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Java file Second Fragment (main activity and first fragment have no issues as far as I know)

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSecondBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentSecondBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view.getId();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        EditText StudentName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentName);
        EditText StudentsAge = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentAge);
        EditText StudentSalary = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentSalary);
        EditText StudentInternational = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentInternational);
        EditText StudentUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentUsername);
        EditText StudentPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentPassword);
        EditText StudentSkills = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentSkills);


        DBHelper Dat = new DBHelper(getContext());


        binding.buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment);
            }
        });
        binding.buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = StudentName.getText().toString();
                String age = StudentsAge.getText().toString();
                String salary = StudentSalary.getText().toString();
                int savedSalary = tryParse(salary);
                String international = StudentInternational.getText().toString();
                String user = StudentUsername.getText().toString();
                String pass = StudentPassword.getText().toString();
                String skills = StudentSkills.getText().toString();
                int savedAge = tryParse(age);
                if(name.equals("")|| age.equals("") || salary.equals("") || international.equals("") || user.equals("") || pass.equals("") || skills.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "A field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(savedSalary == -1 || savedAge == -1){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Salary and Age should be integers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Boolean try1 = Dat.insertData(name,savedAge,skills,savedSalary,international,0);
                    Boolean try2 = Dat.insertSecurity(user, pass);
                    NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this)
                                .navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FourthFragment);
                    }
                }
            
        });
    }
    public Integer tryParse(Object obj) {
        Integer retVal;
        try {
            retVal = Integer.parseInt((String) obj);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            retVal = -1; // or null if that is your preference
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        binding = null;
    }



}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Enter Student Info"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:text="@string/previous"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_second" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_second" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStudentName"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Student Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_second" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStudentSalary"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Enter minimum accepted salary"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextStudentAge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStudentAge"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Enter Student Age"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextStudentName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStudentInternational"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Enter if Internation student, use Y or N"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextStudentSalary" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStudentUsername"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextStudentInternational" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStudentPassword"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextStudentUsername" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStudentSkills"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Enter skills seperated by commas"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextStudentPassword" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Previously deleted as I thought I instantly solved it by adding .getApplicationContext to getContext(), but it turns out it doesn't so I undeleted it as I still have no clue why its happening.  Oh, and by the way, the reason why I use DBhelper Dat = new DBhelper(getContext) or DBhelper Dat = new DBhelper(getContext.getApplicationContext) is because using DBHelper Dat = new DBHelper(this); makes it scream about wanting to change context to second fragment.

Comment: First, uninstall the app and rerun to recreate the tables.

Comment: uninstall android studio, or the app I created?

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device/emulator where you test it.

Comment: tried xing out of the emulator on android studio and replayed it (think that is what you mean), same issue. Even tried creating an entire new device/virtual emulator, same issue still.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, turns out that as @forpas said, the problem with the app was a matter of resetting the device. However, as I had no idea how to do that, or even that it was necessary, I kept on trying even though nothing worked, even though a better term would be "wiping" the app, as the way to do it seems to be the "wipe data" setting.